# How can I split a string input in Javascript by each spacebar, but not elements inside double "quotes", single 'quotes' or backticks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get an array of arguments from a string by doing the following

```js
const str = `argument "second argument" 'third argument' \`fourth argument\``;

str.split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)/g);
```

**The expected output:**

```js
['argument', '"second argument"', "'third argument'", '`fourth argument`']
```

**But this comes out:**

```js
['argument', '`', '"second argument"', '`', "'third argument'", '`', '`fourth argument`']
```

How can I get back an array of just 4 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting an array then you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the unwanted string

```js
const str = `argument "second argument" 'third argument' \`fourth argument\``;

const result = str
  .split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)/g)
  .filter((s) => /[a-z]/.test(s));

console.log(result);
```

You can also achieve the same result using string manipulation

```js
const str = `argument "second argument" 'third argument' \`fourth argument\``;

const replacerFn = (match) => match.split(" ").join("_");
const result = str
  .replace(/".*?"|'.*?'|`.*?`/g, replacerFn)
  .split(" ")
  .map((s) => s.split("_").join(" "));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you standardized your string before split to array

Replace all **`** to **"** and so